# how to get value from two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

What is wrong with this piece of code?

```
<?php
$myarray=array_fill ( 0 , 2 , array_fill (0,1,3) );
echo "> ".$myarray[0][1]." < <br>";
?>
```

Result of above echo commands is following:

```
> <
```

My expectation was '> 3 <' would be displayed.

How to correctly access values of two dimensional array as in this case pls?

Thanks

Comment: there is no $myarray[0][1] try this echo "> ".$myarray[0][0]." < <br>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does indeed create a two dimensional array, however this is the actual data:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    int(3)
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

So `$myarray[0][1]` does not exist.

The outer call to `array_fill()` creates a numerical array with two elements, the inner an array with one element and value `3`. Both key sets start with `0`. That is why you do *not* get a key `1` in the inner array, but only `0` as sole key in there.

Please read the explanation about the arguments to the function as documented: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I know ... it was my fault not reading manual carefully - I thought the second argument in array_fill function stands for 'end index' while it represents number on elements in array.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
foreach($myarray as $val_array)
{
    foreach($val_array as $val)     
    {
        echo  $val."<br>";
    }
}
```

output :

```
3
3
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/FZKiP)**

Answer (score 0):

There is no 1 index in 0'th index $myarray[0][1]

```
<?php

$myarray=array_fill ( 0 , 2 , array_fill (0,1,3) );

echo "<pre>";

print_r($myarray);

echo "</pre>";


 echo "> ".$myarray[0][0]." < <br>";
 ?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
    )

  )

   > 3 <
```